# What happened to Marcus Licinius Crassus' Gold?

Tags: roman-republic

Marcus Licinius Crassus (from the First Triumvirate) was considered to be richest man ever. After his death however, what happened to his immense fortune? It seems like a treasure like that would be noted in the annals, but I haven't seen anything Plutarch about this. Are there any other records?

Comment: Is it possible that Crassus built a secret tomb and it is loaded with gold? Hmmm.

Comment: I suppose (almost) anything is possible, but how would we know?

Comment: 62 back in Roman times was much like 62 today: you're getting on in years, but have a reasonable expectation of another 10-15 or so.

Comment: The correct answers would be: No one knows what happened to the gold, as there is no written record documenting its disposition, and it is _possible_ he had a tomb built and had his gold hid there. It is unlikely, however, as if the gold he was purported to have controlled had ever been found, it surely would have elicited comment.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the speculation and leave the core question; at that point, I suspect @CGCampbell's comment should be converted to an answer.

Comment: Let's see - can anyone think of a reason why Crassus' surviving son (Marcus Licinius Crassus) would not have received it, as per Roman law? (https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1bl126/what_happened_to_the_wealth_of_crassus/)

Comment: Crassus wasn't Scrooge McDuck.  His wealth was in land, investments in businesses and mines, and in loans to influential Romans.  That did not go away when he died in Parthia.

Comment: The notion of buried pirate booty was an invention of Robert Louis Stevenson - no pirate, including Crassus the master himself, ever buried treasure for later recovery.

Comment: Crassus was a very greedy man,despite being the richest man in Rome he  stayed  in Syria for 2 years & accumulated a fortune by taxing the province before he went to war with Parthia.I'm sure he went to great lengths to ensure if he died his money would go where he wanted it to.

Comment: Why the downvote? At elast an explanation could have been given

Answer (score 2):

Well, since Crassus died prematurely (at the [Battle of Carrhae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Carrhae)) during a rebellion that would seem to be unlikely. After all, if he were to have built a tomb it would have been in Italy, not Syria, and since he never got to retire to Rome because the Parthians unexpectedly killed him in battle, I think we can safely assume that whatever plans he had for his final resting place, they were unfulfilled.

Comment: Crassus didn't die in any rebellion.